# How can I change the color value of <input type="color"/> when the page is loaded?

Tags: javascript, html, css, user-interface

I'm trying to make a web page that allows users to pick the color through the color input and the page should store their choices in the localStorage. Ideally, the user should still be able to view the color palette they made next time they open the page.

My problem is that the value of color input doesn't update with my javascript code. I tried to write window.onload, and even insert "onload()" in the  tag. None of them worked. The input still displays the same default color value, which is pure black. I could really use some help on how to solve this.

Thank you so much~

Here's my HTML codes:

```
<body onload="getColor()">
    <div class="container">
        <div id="mySidebar" class="sidebar">
            <label class="noteLabel">C</label>
            <input type="color" id="color0" name="color" onchange="handleChange(this.value, this.id)" />
            <label class="noteLabel">F#</label>
            <input type="color" id="color6" name="color"
                onchange="handleChange(this.value, this.id)" /><br />
            <label class="noteLabel">C#</label>
            <input type="color" id="color1" name="color" onchange="handleChange(this.value, this.id)" />
            <label class="noteLabel">G</label>
            <input type="color" id="color7" name="color" 
                onchange="handleChange(this.value, this.id)" /><br />
            <label class="noteLabel">D</label>
            <input type="color" id="color2" name="color" onchange="handleChange(this.value, this.id)" />
            <label class="noteLabel">G#</label>
            <input type="color" id="color8" name="color" 
                onchange="handleChange(this.value, this.id)" /><br />
            <label class="noteLabel">D#</label>
            <input type="color" id="color3" name="color" onchange="handleChange(this.value, this.id)" />
            <label class="noteLabel">A</label>
            <input type="color" id="color9" name="color" 
                onchange="handleChange(this.value, this.id)" /><br />
            <label class="noteLabel">E</label>
            <input type="color" id="color4" name="color" onchange="handleChange(this.value, this.id)" />
            <label class="noteLabel">A#</label>
            <input type="color" id="color10" name="color" 
                onchange="handleChange(this.value, this.id)" /><br />
            <label class="noteLabel">F</label>
            <input type="color" id="color5" name="color" onchange="handleChange(this.value, this.id)" />
            <label class="noteLabel">B</label>
            <input type="color" id="color11" name="color"
                onchange="handleChange(this.value, this.id)" /><br />
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Here are the JavaScript codes that I used to change the default color value:

```
var customColor = [[255, 0, 0], [255, 0, 0], [255, 0, 0], [255, 0, 0], [255, 0, 0], [255, 0, 0], [255, 0, 0], [255, 0, 0], [255, 0, 0], [255, 0, 0], [255, 0, 0], [255, 0, 0]];

window.onload = function () {
    customColor.forEach((item, index) => {
        let tem_id = "color" + index
        console.log(rgbToHex(item))
        document.getElementById(tem_id).setAttribute('defaultValue', '#' + rgbToHex(item));
    })
}

function getColor(){
    customColor.forEach((item, index) => {
        let tem_id = "color" + index
        console.log(rgbToHex(item))
        document.getElementById(tem_id).setAttribute('defaultValue', '#' + rgbToHex(item));
    })
}
```

Comment: First, I would [get rid of ALL the inline HTML event attributes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43459890/javascript-function-doesnt-work-when-link-is-clicked/43459991#43459991), which are 25+ year old ways to set up events and just will not die the death they deserve because people don't take the time to understand their shortcomings and just use them with reckless abandon. They bloat up your code and don't provide any separation of concerns as well as creating global wrappers around your DOM objects that alter the `this` bindings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just figured out what's wrong with my code. It turned out that the function `rgbToHex()` I defined wasn't working properly, so the value input element received wasn't in the correct format. I didn't notice that until now because the console only mentioned this problem as a warning.

Answer (score 0):

Please use `value` instead of `defaultValue`. Look Code below:

```js
document.getElementById("color11").value = "#ff0000";
```

```html
<input type="color" id="color11" name="color"
                onchange="handleChange(this.value, this.id)" />
```

Comment: I did use "value" at first, then switch to "defaultValue". Neither of them worked for me though

Comment: @URlemontree put your code that use `value` to know what is problem.